# Which SQL query is more efficient and why?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, entity-attribute-value

I wrote 2 queries with the same result and both are performing equal when i run them. Though i'm curious if the efficiency is the same for both as i cannot imagine that they are.

I think this one is less efficient:

```
SELECT post.ID, 
    post.post_title ticket_id, 
    (SELECT meta_value 
        FROM wp_postmeta post_meta
        WHERE post_meta.post_id = post.ID 
            && post_meta.meta_key = "WooCommerceEventsPurchaserFirstName") first_name,
    (SELECT meta_value 
        FROM wp_postmeta post_meta
        WHERE post_meta.post_id = post.ID 
            && post_meta.meta_key = "WooCommerceEventsPurchaserLastName") last_name,
    (SELECT meta_value 
        FROM wp_postmeta post_meta
        WHERE post_meta.post_id = post.ID 
            && post_meta.meta_key = "WooCommerceEventsPurchaserEmail") email,
    (SELECT meta_value 
        FROM wp_postmeta post_meta
        WHERE post_meta.post_id = post.ID 
            && post_meta.meta_key = "WooCommerceEventsPurchaserPhone") phone,
    (SELECT meta_value 
        FROM wp_postmeta post_meta
        WHERE post_meta.post_id = post.ID 
            && post_meta.meta_key = "WooCommerceEventsProductID") product_id,
    (SELECT meta_value 
        FROM wp_postmeta post_meta
        WHERE post_meta.post_id = post.ID 
            && post_meta.meta_key = "WooCommerceEventsVariations") ticket_type,
    (SELECT meta_value 
        FROM wp_postmeta 
        WHERE post_id = product_id
            && meta_key = "_sku") SKU
FROM wp_posts post 
WHERE post_type = "event_magic_tickets"
```

Than this one because i do less (select) queries but i do a JOIN which is heavier than a select?

```
SELECT post.ID ID, 
         post.post_title ticket_id,
         customers.*,
         (SELECT meta_value 
            FROM wp_postmeta 
            WHERE post_id = product_id
            && meta_key = "_sku") SKU
FROM wp_posts post 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT post_id id,
    MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'WooCommerceEventsPurchaserFirstName' THEN meta_value END) first_name,
    MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'WooCommerceEventsPurchaserLastName' THEN meta_value END) last_name,
    MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'WooCommerceEventsPurchaserEmail' THEN meta_value END) email,
    MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'WooCommerceEventsPurchaserPhone' THEN meta_value END) phone,
    MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'WooCommerceEventsProductID' THEN meta_value END) product_id,
    MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'WooCommerceEventsVariations' THEN meta_value END) ticket_type
    FROM wp_postmeta post_meta
    GROUP BY post_id) customers
    ON customers.id = post.id
WHERE post_type = "event_magic_tickets";
```

Can someone explain me which one is more efficient and why? (and maybe how to measure this so i can do it my self in the future). I use MariaDB in case it matters..

Comment: I'd bet on the second query. I suppose that `WHERE post_type = 'event_magic_tickets'` applies to a very small amount of the posts. If MariaDB featured it, I would probably use the second query with a `LEFT JOIN LATERAL` in that case. Luckily, MariaDB tries to detect such situation and apply this internally as of version 10.3 (https://mariadb.com/kb/en/lateral-derived-optimization/). While the first query looks straight forward, an index access before the table access is needed for every single expression. In the second query we need an index access only once per post_id probably.

Comment: ... All this provided that there is an index on `post_meta (post_id, meta_key)` of course. I'd consider this careless negligence, if there wasn't.

Answer (score 2):

You need to test on *your* data and your system to see which works better.  They will definitely have different execution plans.

As a general rule for this type of query, one or two joins is often faster than aggregation.  However, the aggregation query tends to scale better -- that is, it starts off slow but each new column is just a small amount of effort.

I do note, though, that you are aggregating *before* filtering.  That likely means that you are aggregating lots of posts that don't need to be aggregated -- and that extra work is expensive.  You really want to filter the data as much as possible before aggregation.

Comment: I understand what you are saying but i have still some questions. -- I aggregate in both queries don't i? The second one does also a JOIN so this is, according to the "general rule" less efficient?  --  How can i filter before aggregating? you mean that i should also add a  `WHERE` in the JOIN sub query so it reduces the aggregations?

Comment: Starting with version 10.3 MariaDB is able to apply lateral derived optimaziation: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/lateral-derived-optimization/. With many possible meta_keys per post_id, it may still help to add a where clause in the subquery: `where meta_key in ('WooCommerceEventsPurchaserFirstName', 'WooCommerceEventsPurchaserLastName', ...)`.

Answer (score 2):

Both approaches can be sped up by suitable changes to the indexes.  The key is to have `(post_id, meta_key)`.  More details:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#speeding_up_wp_postmeta

Also, check to see if there is an index *starting with* `post_type`.

For further discussion, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the relevant tables.